# Is there a way to only list windows of the current session in tmux?

Tags: tmux

When I use leader_key + w all the windows from all the session shows up.
Is there an easy way to show and select windows from the current session only ?

Comment: The best way I have figured out is to list all windows by pressing leader_key and then :list-windows. For selection leader_key + 3 (Window number you want to select)

Comment: No easy way to do this. But a work around might be

`Ctl-a + s` and then `l`.

Answer (score 0):

I added to my tmux config a custom command (binded to leader_key + a) to show the active windows. This is what I have in my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key a resize-pane -Z \; choose-tree "resize-pane -Z \; select-window -t '%%'"
```

the end result is a view off all the open window in the current session with the option to select one:

```
(0)  - 0: 3 windows (attached)
(1)  ├─>   1: less* (1 panes) "pi@raspberry: ~"
(2)  ├─>   2: bash (1 panes) 
(3)  └─> - 3: MachineLearning- (2 panes)
(4)      ├─> 1: octave-gui 
(5)      └─> 2: vim
```

Comment: I'm running tmux 3.1b and the above mapping doesn't produce the desired affect. For me it further expands windows into panes.